# Gmail drops connection in Firefox

Tags: firefox, gmail

I've used Gmail almost since it started, and Firefox for even longer. But recently they've been seemingly incompatible. After a few minutes of using Gmail on Firefox, I get an error banner at the top of the screen ("Oops... the system encountered a problem #001") and it won't let me use it any more (to be clear: I can read and change labels, but the changes aren't synced). So it seems like the connection has been severed.

This issue only applies to my work laptop (Windows 10), and only then using Firefox - it's fine with Chrome. Other websites are unaffected.

I've tried "Troubleshoot Mode" (all addons disabled), clearing cookies and cache, and finally "Refresh Firefox" (all addons and customisations disabled).

Any ideas how to go about diagnosing this? I'm happy to use Developer Tools but I'm not sure what I'm looking for.

Comment: > `it's fine with Chrome``.
Remind me who makes Chrome and who make Gmail. I am not surprised.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that it sometimes is not resolving the URL.

Disabling hardware acceleration may help...
https://support.mozilla.org/bm/questions/1202915

What is weird is that it will probably work fine in private tab mode. At least thats what solves the problem for me (even with all extensions enabled in private tab mode).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For me, it's a bad interaction between Gmail, Firefox and Sophos.

Change the security.tls.enable_0rtt_data setting to false in Firefox to fix the issue.

Although the problem described in this post isn't exactly what you describe, disabling this about:config setting is recommended for Gmail connectivity trouble in Firefox v100+ here:
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1376015

Comment: Your answer needs a citation or reference

Comment: Hmm, interesting. We definitely use Sophos so there might be something in that. I'll give it a try if necessary. In the meantime the problem seems to have gone away mostly anyway...